# Why do two values lose their value in the dictionary

Tags: vb.net

I have a dictionary that I populate like this:

```
Dim RoomInfo As New Dictionary(Of Integer, GuestInfo)
Dim guestCount As Integer = 1

For Each guest As Guest in Room
    guest.Code = code
    guest.Name = name
    RoomInfo.Add(guestCount, guest)
    guestCount = guestCount + 1
Next
```

In another part of the code, I add more guests to the dictionary within a for each

```
For Each guest As Guest in Room
    guest.Code = code
    guest.Name = name
    guest.Adults = adults
    guest.Children = children
    RoomInfo.Add(guestCount, guest)
    guestCount = guestCount + 1
    RoomInfo.Add(RoomInfo.Count + 1, guest)
 Next
```

I can't figure out why, but when I step through the code, I see the Adults and Children have the correct values, but it is then zero'd out.

Here is an example:

In the initial loop, I do not assign adults and children to the structure (Guest).

In the second loop, I check to see if the Room has an assigned guest and if it does not I create a new structure (Guest) and I add that to the Room List.   So in the first loop, I may have 2 records, but in the second loop, I have to add a 3rd record, but when I do this, it seems like the 3rd record gets the adult/children count from the 2nd record and the 2nd record gets zero'd out.

Comment: Dictionary's keys must be unique. I cannot see how you want to keep them unique if they rely on a count. If you'd use a Room-Number as key that might be a viable approach.

Comment: But they are unique, when I add another guest, I am incrementing the key to be one higher than the dictionary count.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Although you are right, that doesn't seem to be the problem here. As long as guestCount stays unique

Comment: And it does not give any errors and like I said above, it is only the adults and children that are not being populated correctly.

Comment: Then you're abusing a Dictionary's key as indexer. Either way there's something odd. Since it's not clear what you actually need the dictionary for, i cannot suggest a better approach. If i would have to guess, i would suggest to use a RoomID(if available) as key and a List(Of GuestInfo) as value.

Comment: @Xaisoft You wrote in your question that 'two' values are lost, can you be more specific on that?

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but what is `RoomInfo.Add(RoomInfo.Count + 1, guest)` supposed to do?

Comment: Room is just an xml element.   RoomInfo.Add is added a guest to the RoomInfo list.  Guest is a structure type to, don't know if that has an effect on it.

Comment: I meant why you're adding the `Guest` twice, once with the index being `guestCount` and the other being `RoomInfo.Count + 1`.

Comment: Because if I use guestCount, it will try to add a to an existing key.

Comment: What is the difference between Guest and GuestInfo?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - Guest refers to one guest (a structure type in this case), GuestInfo is just what I called the list to hold all the guests.

Comment: Guest should be a Class not a Structure. Classes are way easier to work with.

Comment: @Meta-Knight - Changing from a Structure to a class did not change the output.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your problem, other than the exception that should occur in your second loop that will only _not_ occur if you add 0 or 1 `Guests` without having removed any beforehand. I don't believe the problem lies in the code you've given.

Comment: @Timiz0r - Are you using strings or ints for adults/children?

Comment: I've now used both with no problems.

Comment: Can you add to your code the structure Guest and whatever is GuestInfo.

Answer (score 0):

You might try making the key a character -- perhaps the payor's name and the date, i.e., `Dim mykey As String = {Lastname & "_" & Firstname & "_" & RoomNumber}`, and then stack all of the data for guests and the room in a string list:

```
Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
```